# difference between oldest and youngest birthdates

Tags: sql, date, datediff

I am trying to write a query in order to pull up the age difference between the oldest and youngest pilots in my pilots table

heres what I have except the problem is I need it to be in `years` not `days`:

```
SELECT ROUND(MAX(PIL_BRTHDATE)-(MIN(PIL_BRTHDATE),2) AS "AGE DIFFERENCE" FROM PILOTS;
```

THE ROUND IS THERE BECAUSE MY PROFESSOR WANTS IT ROUNDED TO THE 2ND DECIMAL

I TRIED THE `DATEDIFF` FUNCTION BUT SINCE I CANT JUST INPUT THE START DATES AND END DATES MANUALLY ITS NOT WORKING (`YY,"STARTDATE", "ENDDATE"`)

FOR EXAMPLE I TRIED:

```
DATEDIFF(YY,MAX(PIL_BRTHDATE),MIN(PIL_BRTHDATE))...IT KEEPS SAYING INVALID IDENTIFIER
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: whats the dbms u r using... its working for sql server ---http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fabe0/5

Comment: I am using oracle sql developer

Answer (score 1):

EXTRACT (YEAR FROM YOUR DATES)